# How to Scale a GLFW window

Tags: opengl, glfw

I am creating a GLFW window with the size of 1920 X 1080.

I want to scale down the size of the window to 1920 / 2 X 1080 / 2 without reducing the size of framebuffer.

Basically the window should be displayed in the size of 1920 / 2 X 1080 / 2 but the framebuffer should be of size 1920 X 1080.

If i try to do this step manually by making the window with GLFW_RESIZABLE than the framebuffer_size_callback seems to be reducing the size of the framebuffer.

Comment: Render scene to full-resolution FBO, blit FBO to the half-sized default framebuffer?

Comment: For what do you need twice the resolution? If your goal is too make triangle edges smoother by using twice the resolution (super sampling), then there is another technique that is more performant and gives you the same results (multi sampling [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Anti-Aliasing))

Comment: @Felix Brüll i am outputting the data of default framebuffer through glMapBuffer for SDI output and the window size of 1920 X 1080 is too large for the designer to design the scene.

Comment: so i want to keep outputting the data of the default framebuffer but window size should be small.

Comment: What you want is not possible. The default framebuffer is always tied to the size of the window. See also [How to make OpenGL rendering resolution independent from its window context resolution?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72677/how-to-make-opengl-rendering-resolution-independent-from-its-window-context-reso)